# Npgsql GetDateTime now returns utc instead of local time?

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, npgsql

We have migrated from Npgsql 5 to version 8, and now query from the example below is returning time in UTC, whereas previously it returned local time. The SQL function Now itself returns "timestamp with timezone". I generally use the GetDateTime function to read time from tables as well. What am I doing wrong?

```
using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT \"now\"()", conn))
{
    using (NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (dr.Read() == true)
        {
            now = dr.GetDateTime(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems to be the current standard behavior. You might want to read the [docs](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/datetime.html) and follow the release notes link there also to get the rational of the change.

Comment: Thank you @Ralf, I've also figured it out. I just need to adjust my code accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a comprehensive change in how timestamp are handled in Npgsql 6.0. [See the release notes here](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/release-notes/6.0.html#timestamp-rationalization-and-improvements), and especially the breaking changes section, which contains some mitigation instructions.